# how to delete duplicate grease pencil strokes

Tags: grease-pencil

I think i copied and pasted some strokes, which resulted in 2 duplicate strokes in the same location. How can i clean it? i've tried to click a stroke to select one of the duplicates and delete it, which is how i found out there were duplicates, but there are hundreds of strokes and it would be too tedious to select every single one and deleting the duplicate, so i was wondering if there was another way.